# Add a device to an internal tester in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I just added an internal tester account in iTunesConnect and set it's roles to Adminand save it, the email arrived to the user and everything was set up, but in the Testing Profile of the user it doesn't show any devices, so the question is: how can IU add a device? and how can I send a build to the newly added internal tester?

Comment: Have you sent a build to this user yet?

Comment: yes, I have submitted a build and one of the user seems to have 2 devices and the other one says that it doesn't retrieve the email and he doesn't seem to have any devices set

Comment: Were they added as a tester before the build was uploaded? Try upload a new build and distribute it to testers again. Make sure they check they spam folder too.

Comment: I will do that right now, I'll let you know if it fixes the issue and you could convert the comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add the device. If you login to iTunesConnect, go to **Users&Roles -> Testflight-BetaTesters -> Internal**. There you should see the person you added.

Once your tester has accepted the invitation in the email you can go to **Apps -> YourApp -> Prerelease**. Then add him. Your tester needs to download Testflight from the AppStore and login. That should work, then he installs the app to test.